# Prove that $\bigcup_{s \in S} \bigcap_{t \in T_s}A_t=\bigcap_{Y \in \mathcal{K}} \bigcup_{t \in Y}A_t$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $T=\bigcup_{s \in S} T_s$ and let $\mathcal{K}$ be the family of all subsets of $T$ which have at least one element in common with each set $T_s$. Prove that:

$$\bigcup_{s \in S} \bigcap_{t \in T_s}A_t=\bigcap_{Y \in \mathcal{K}} \bigcup_{t \in Y}A_t$$

I tried to analyze the problem by writing down individual sets and considering how various sums and intersections may look like but I am unable to make any significant progress.

Comment: What is $A_t$ here?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose first that

$$x\in\bigcup_{s\in S}\bigcap_{t\in T_s}A_t\;;$$

then there is some $s_0\in S$ such that

$$x\in\bigcap_{t\in T_{s_0}}A_t\;.$$

We want to show that

$$x\in\bigcap_{Y\in\mathscr{K}}\bigcup_{t\in Y}A_t\;,\tag{1}$$

so let $Y\in\mathscr{K}$. By definition there is some $t_Y\in Y\cap T_{s_0}$, so

$$x\in A_{t_Y}\subseteq\bigcup_{t\in Y}A_t\;;$$

this proves $(1)$, since $Y$ was an arbitrary member of $\mathscr{K}$, and we conclude that

$$\bigcup_{s\in S}\bigcap_{t\in T_s}A_t\subseteq\bigcap_{Y\in\mathscr{K}}\bigcup_{t\in Y}A_t\;.$$

Now suppose that

$$x\notin\bigcup_{s\in S}\bigcap_{t\in T_s}A_t\;;\tag{2}$$

we want to show that $(1)$ is false. $(2)$ implies that for each $s\in S$ there is a $t_s\in T_s$ such that $x\notin A_{t_s}$; Let $Y_0=\{t_s:s\in S\}$. Then by definition $Y_0\in\mathscr{K}$, but

$$x\notin\bigcup_{s\in S}A_{t_s}=\bigcup_{t\in Y_0}A_t\;,$$

so

$$x\notin\bigcap_{Y\in\mathscr{K}}\bigcup_{t\in Y}A_t\;,$$

as desired. This shows that

$$\bigcap_{Y\in\mathscr{K}}\bigcup_{t\in Y}A_t\subseteq\bigcup_{s\in S}\bigcap_{t\in T_s}A_t\;,$$

completing the proof that

$$\bigcap_{Y\in\mathscr{K}}\bigcup_{t\in Y}A_t=\bigcup_{s\in S}\bigcap_{t\in T_s}A_t\;.$$